# 400 error when making POST request (adding item to SP list)

Tags: list, javascript, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I have a form that contains check boxes and input fields, and hitting the Submit button should ideally add the content values to a SP list.

When I run the debugger I can see that each input (checked items, text inputs, etc) is getting passed into `addItemToSPList`, but when I open the Network tab I see the following error:

> "value: "A node of type 'StartArray' was read from the JSON reader when trying to read a value of a property; however, a 'PrimitiveValue' or 'StartObject' node was expected."

I am suspecting that something's wrong within my `ajax` block (perhaps the URL), but I'm not 100% sure.

Any thoughts on what's going on?

---

JS code:

```
  handleClick() {
    let specialtiesArr = [],
        regionsArr = [],
        commentsArr = [],
        nameArr = [];
    
    $(".check-spec:checked").each(function() {
        specialtiesArr.push($(this).val());
    })

    $(".check-region:checked").each(function() {
        regionsArr.push($(this).val());
    })

    commentsArr.push($('.request-text-area').val());
    nameArr.push($('.submitter-name').val());

    addItemToSPList(specialtiesArr, regionsArr, commentsArr, nameArr)
  }

} // export default class closing bracket

  function addItemToSPList(getSpecialties, getRegions, getComments, getSubmitterName) {
        let specialistRequestsColumns = {
            "__metadata":{"type": "SP.Data.Specialist_x0020_RequestsListItem"},
            "Title": "No Title", // marked it as "not required" in the SP list backend
            "Specialties": { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, results: getSpecialties }, // multi-select
            "Regions": { '__metadata': { 'type' : 'Collection(Edm.String)'}, results: getRegions }, // multi-select
            "Comments": getComments, // text box
            "Submitter_x0020_Name": getSubmitterName // input field
        }
    
        let listName = "Specialist%20Requests";
        $.ajax({
            url: `${_BaseHost}/redacted/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('${listName}')/items`, // ?$select=ListItemEntityTypeFullName
            method: "POST", // type
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            data: JSON.stringify(specialistRequestsColumns),
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: data => {
                console.log("upload successful")
                // console.log(data)
            },error: (err) => {
                console.log("Error: " + err);
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: What is stored in `getSpecialties` and `getRegions`? Is there any other required column in your list for which you are not passing any value?

Comment: @GaneshSanap The values of `getSpecialties` and `getRegions` are checked checkboxes, and when a box is checked it's added to an array (I added the rest of the `handleClick()` code above). Also, all of the columns are listed above and none are required.

Comment: At first glance I would say it might be either the `Comments` or `SubmitterName` (or both).  By your code comments you seem to be implying that the `Comments` field is a text input, not a collection, so I would think that SharePoint is expecting a string (primitive value), yet you are putting that single string into an array `commentsArr.push($('.request-text-area').val());` before sending it to SP.

Comment: @DylanCristy that's exactly what happened, and both you and Ganesh were on the money. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is an issue with single line of text fields in your code. Try using below code for Comments and Submitter Name:

```
var comments, submitterName;
comments = $('.request-text-area').val();
submitterName = $('.submitter-name').val();

addItemToSPList(specialtiesArr, regionsArr, comments, submitterName):
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. I was too focused on the `addItemToSPList` block and didn't really think about the `handleClick()`. Thank you!